# POST request of an array into JSON with Retrofit 2 Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, retrofit2

I am a begginer in android.
I want to add a comment into a post, I tried many solutions but none worked.
When I test the API in postman it works but I don't know how to make it in android.

**This is my Entity in nodejs**

```
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    text: String,
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    date: Date,
    image: String,
    idUser: String,
    comments: [{
        text: String,
        date: Date,
        idUser: String,
    }],
```

**This is the API**

```
router.post('/comments/:idPost', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.idPost;
    Post.updateOne({ _id: id }, {
        $addToSet: {
            comments: [{
                text: req.body.comments.text,
                date: Date.now(),
                idUser: req.body.comments.idUser
            }],
        }
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my Entity in Java**

```
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String idPost;
    @SerializedName("text")
    private String text;
    @SerializedName("likes")
    private int likes;
    @SerializedName("date")
    private Date date;
    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("idUser")
    private String idUser;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    private ArrayList<Comment> CommentArrayList;

    public static class Comment {
        @SerializedName("_id")
        private String idComment;
        @SerializedName("text")
        private String text;
        @SerializedName("date")
        private Date date;
        @SerializedName("idUser")
        private String idUser; }
}
```

**This is the request I made**

```
@POST("/posts/comments/{idPost}")
    Call<ResponseBody> addComment(@Path("idPost") String idPost, @Body JSONObject comment);
```

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons this doesn't work. Can you provide a stack trace or any kind of debug output Retrofit provides when you attempt to do your POST call?

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand your question well.
I can explain how to send data into node JS using retrofit2

In android, add this line in the Retrofit interface

```
@POST("/user/phone/verify")
Call<Void> addNewComment(@Body HashMap<String, String> map);
```

And add your details about comment here :

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id","your id");
        map.put("image","your image");
        map.put("comment","your comment");
        map.put("password",password);
```

Then this code call the post method as the above HashMap as body

```
Call<Void> call = retrofitInterface.executeSignUp(map);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.code()==200){
                    //Success
                   
                }else {
                    //An error ocuurred
                    
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ServerCallback", "onFailure: ",t);
            }
        });
```